# Arduino ZG2100-based WiShield library, no MAC address

Tags: arduino, wifi

I've been playing with using my Arduino (a Redback, basically a WiFi module/Arduino Nano combo) and the WiServer library to POST data to websites, and it seems to be working fine. However, when I use netcats and try to get the Arduino to connect to my local PC, netcats keeps telling me the connection is invalid since the Arduino has no known MAC address. The problem is, I can't see any initialization functions etc in the WiServer library that would allow me to specify a MAC address. As for using other libraries, my device doesn't support anything else other than WiServer and some other support libraries based on uIP.

Does anyone have a suggestion? Or can anyone explain to me how I can connect to a website but not to my local PC?

Comment: Taking a brief look at that library, it seems that the MAC address is supposed to get set in `zg_drv_process` when initializing the connection, so either something is going wrong in the init process or netcats is wrong.

Comment: How did you find that out so quickly?

Answer (score 1):

For those  stuck with the ZG2100-based WiShield library, the only way I found to set the MAC is to hard-code it into the library. The MAC field is found in g2100.c. In my case, I set it like this:

static U8 mac[6] = { 0x00, 0x1E, 0xC0, 0x04, 0x9F, 0xF3 };